# Ant build doesn't make jar file

Tags: java, ant, build, jar

Got my hands on an old script from year 2000.
It's all in Java and there is a build file which compiles it all:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <project name="chat" default="compile" basedir=".">
        <target name="init">
            <property name="conf.dir" value="conf" />
            <property name="src.dir" value="src" />
            <property name="resource.dir" value="resource" />
            <property name="build.dir" value="build" />     
            <property name="release.dir" value="release" />
            <property name="etc.dir" value="etc" />
            <property name="lib.dir" value="lib" />
        </target>



        <target name="clean" depends="init">
            <delete dir="${build.dir}" />       
            <delete dir="${release.dir}" />
        </target>

        <target name="compile" depends="init">
            <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
            <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" includeAntRuntime="false" debug="true" optimize="false" />        
        </target>

        <target name="release" depends="compile">       
            <mkdir dir="${release.dir}" />

            <jar destfile="${release.dir}/chat_service.jar" basedir="${build.dir}"  includeantruntime="false" />        
        </target>

    </project>
```

When I run it with ant in Windows the command prompt says:

```
Buildfile: build.xml

init: 

compile: BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

But it doesn't create a jar file.
All it does is copy the exact project and compile it into class files.

Does anyone know how I can create the right file? 
It's a chat server and I need it to run my client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default target of the build file is `compile`:

```
<project name="chat" default="compile" basedir=".">
```

So if you invoke ant without specifying a target, the `compile` target will be executed. To execute the `release` target, use

```
ant release
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add another target section for generating the jar file.
For instance :

```
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}" />
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}" />
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="config/ properties/ ${manifest.classpath}" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>

</target>
```

at the end, of course you should configure that block for your own file and properties.

Comment: There is no need to add an additional target, because there already is one with a jar task. It just needs to be executed/used (ant release)