# Intellij generated Ant Build File, doesn't build jar

Tags: java, ant, jar, intellij-idea

I am trying to create a jar using the Intellij Generated Ant Build.

- I am using Intellij 12.1.4
- I am using Java 1.6.0_51 (Default on Mac).

When I create the ant build I am using the following options:

- Generate single-file ant build
- Overwrite previously generated files
- Use JDK definitions from project files
- Inline runtime classpaths

I then run the following command on my command line

```
ant -f buildfile.xml
```

It looks like it works on the command line.  There are a few notes, but no errors.  When it finishes it says BUILD SUCCESSFUL.  However a .jar is never created.

I found this link:  [Ant build doesn't make jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782480/ant-build-doesnt-make-jar-file) which seems to be my problem.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to create a "release" build file from Intellij.  I copied my current ant build file and renamed it "build.xml" and ran the command ant release.  When I ran that command I got the following error:

BUILD FAILED
Target "release" does not exist in the project "MyProject"

Any further help or ideas for next steps would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.

I had to go to open the Project Settings (F4) and then went to Artifacts.  That allowed me to set the settings to create the jar when I ran "ant -f buildfile.xml"